# Typeorm query not returning anything

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have the following code in my ts project

```js
const property = await this.propertyRepo.createQueryBuilder('pr')
      .select(['pr.*'])
      .addSelect(
        '(SELECT ARRAY_AGG(i.url) FROM image i JOIN property p ON i.id = ANY(p."imageIds") WHERE pr.id = p.id)',
        'links',
      ).getMany();
console.log(property);
return property;
```

the query is correct however it does not return anything, just an empty array `[]`.

I have the property table with `imageIds` array of integer column. In `Image` table, I have `id` and `link` fields. I need to return property fields and add array of links according to `imageIds` column.
I expect something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Hotel",
        "stars": 5,
        "city": 0,
        "address": "Mangilik 12",
        "languageSpoken": [1,2],
        "checkInFrom": "12:00:00",
        "checkInTo": "13:00:00",
        "checkOutFrom": "11:00:00",
        "checkOutTo": "11:59:00",
        "category": 0,
        "contactName": "John Doe",
        "contactPhone1": "555-555-5555",
        "contactPhone2": "555-555-1234",
        "services": [1,2,3],
        "links": [
            "image1.jpg",
            "image2.jpg"
        ]
    }
]
```